# One time phone verification while signing up

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

I am using Azure Mobile App service and using azure AD B2C for authentication. I see B2C supports multi-factor authentication. But what I am able to do is, I can activate multi-factor authentication during every authentication and sign up. What I want is to verify the user's phone number only once when the user wants to add the phone number to the profile. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: so during the registration process you'll put a phone number that is not required. In case user fill it, you want to validate, right?

Comment: Right. And the user can also add the phone number later on and it will be verified then.

Answer (score 1):

Today an Azure AD B2C policy either "prompts for and requires MFA" or "does not prompt for and does not require MFA".

There are some customers of Azure AD B2C today that will allow you to sign-in without MFA, and then trigger the "sign-in with MFA policy" when they attempt to access a secure section of the website.

However, I'm interpreting your requirement is to allow some customers to opt-in to MFA, and once they do, their account should only be accessible using MFA.  This may be possible, but it would require a workaround:

1. Add a custom attribute to the directory to maintain whether each user wants MFA or does not want MFA (let's call it "requireMFA").
2. Create two polices in Azure AD B2C "signupsignin_with_mfa", "signupsignin_without_mfa".  Both polices would be configured to return "requireMFA" as a claim.
3. After users sign-in without MFA you could offer a link to "Add MFA", and send them to the signupsignin_with_mfa policy that requires MFA.  At this point, Azure AD B2C will prompt the user to enter a second factor if it does not exist. If your relying party application receives a token back from the signupsignin_with_mfa, that means a second factor was added.  The application should call the Graph API to update the "requireMFA" property to TRUE.
4. Now when a user logs in with signupsignin_without_mfa but the requireMFA is set to TRUE, your application knows that it must send them to the signupsignin_with_mfa policy before allowing access.

Comment: I'm quite new to MFA. I don't know how to do all of this with Azure mobile app integration. Can you please explain that or guide me to a source?

Comment: And there is a little difference. I want to use MFA as a phone number verification module. Whenever the user updates the profile with the phone number he should be asked to verify the MFA once and only once. Subsequent logins do not need the MFA.

Comment: So once the end user provides the phone number, you will not use it for the purpose of authentication?  Sounds like this is not multi-factor authentication, but rather "verify an updated phone number on profile update"?  Unfortunately, Azure AD B2C does not support this.  You could add this feature to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c